# Is it a good idea to have common function for decrypting purpose?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Recently I have been doing a project that involve on having all of the incoming API request encrypted for security purpose. Obviously, my web application need to decrypt that request before I can use the content of the request itself for other purpose. As my web application act like a middle man between 2 party, ideally I would have a lot of API. To ease the development time, I built a common function for the decryption logic. Is it a good thing to do? Is there any security issue on system design perspective?

Comment: This is opinionated. I suggest you edit it before it gets closed :?

Comment: @Aniox hello. I am quite new to posting on overflow stack. Why did you say that it's going to gets closed?